# Computing the upper convex hull in 3d using Qhull

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull, qhull

I am trying to compute the upper convex hull of a cloud of point in 3D using Qhull. I do not know if there is a simple way to do it.

I've looked into several options of the modules ConvexHull and Delaunay, 'Qu' furthest site, but i do not think it does what I want, as it seems to be a way of computing the Delaunay triangulation using lower/upper convex hulls.

Another way of engineering a solution could be for each simplice of the convex hull to compute the normal and the center point of the surface, as to introduce a new point close to the center following a translation upon the normal.

Having added this point I could just compute the convex hull of the original ensemble plus this point and see if this point is interior to the hull or not.

I could then deduce if the simplice belongs to the upper and/or the lower hull.

Comment: The solution I proposed (new point close to the center of a face) works, just not very elegant